# Print a text from a widget located in a sidebar in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to print a text from a widget located in a sidebar, when I use the code below, I get an array that looks like the following:
Array ([0] => text-2 [1] => text-3)

How can I print the text in text-2?

```
$siderbar = 'lank_i_header';

$the_sidebars = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
print_r( $the_sidebars[$siderbar]);
```

I tried with the following code also but it just print "text-2"

```
print_r($the_sidebars[$siderbar][0] );
```

Comment: what is it really that you want to do? thats already correct

Comment: text-2 is a text widget that contains text, I want to print the text in the text widget

Answer (score -1):

try

```
foreach ($the_sidebars[$siderbar] as $sidebar_data){
    echo $sidebar_data.'<br>';
}
```